# Get correct page title on dynamic page?

Tags: ajax

I'm using a script from https://css-tricks.com/rethinking-dynamic-page-replacing-content/ to partially refresh pages.

But the title of the page remains unchanged and is thus confusing to users.

Is there a sensible solution to amend that script?

Comment: What did you tried yourself? Have you made a minimum working example?

Comment: The above url has a working example of the code as-is... the direct url for which is http://sudojesse.github.io/dynamic-page/index.html.

As can be seen, the page title remains unchanged - hence my asking for  help with a suitable mod.

Answer (score 0):

You can change page title as you load pages in ajax with
`document.title='sometitle'`

Comment: My albeit very limited understanding is that when Ajax is used to pull in the content of the requested page, the page title remains that of the original page, not the subsequent page you're viewing.

So an appropriate script needs to parse the title of the page pulled via Ajax, and change the title attribute of the parent document to match.

Comment: Read SO rules first... Before posting anything to SO you have to post a code sample you have tried